# onComplete() does not get called in node cron

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron

Hi i am trying to test out `node-cron` but i am not able to get desired response in one case.

I need to initiate cron request one more time when current cron gets completed. So, i need `onComplete()` to get called but i am not able to get the callback.

**My code snippet is :**

```
CronWrapper.prototype.pushNotificationCron = function() {
    // change console to winston in real implementation.
    console.log('Creating job');
    var jobPattern = '*/10 * * * * *';
    var job = new CronJob(jobPattern, onJobStarted, onJobCompleted, false);
    console.log('Starting job');
    job.start();
};

var onJobStarted = function(){
    var date = new Date();
    console.log('Cron started on \t' + date);
    return;
};

var onJobCompleted = function(){
    winston.info('Job completed:');
};
```

**Output:**

```
Cron started on     Tue Dec 16 2014 12:59:40 GMT+0530 (IST)
Cron started on     Tue Dec 16 2014 12:59:50 GMT+0530 (IST)
Cron started on     Tue Dec 16 2014 13:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

Please point out what mistake i am making.

**Lib details:**

"cron":"1.0.5"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reading documentation more closely, i found i was missing calling stop().

As stated on documentation

> onComplete - [OPTIONAL] - A function that will fire when the job is
>   complete, **when it is stopped**.

So now i am manually calling the `stop()` on completion and getting the callback. So now my code looks like:

```
CronWrapper.prototype.pushNotificationCron = function() {
    // change console to winston in real implementation.
    console.log('Creating job');
    var jobPattern = '*/10 * * * * *';
    var job = new CronJob(jobPattern, function(){
        var date = new Date();
        console.log('Cron started on \t' + date);
        job.stop();
    }, onJobCompleted, false);
    console.log('Starting job');
    job.start();
};

// var onJobStarted = function(){
//  var date = new Date();
//  console.log('Cron started on \t' + date);

// };

var onJobCompleted = function(){
    winston.info('Job completed:');
};
```

**Output**

```
Cron started on     Tue Dec 16 2014 13:13:30 GMT+0530 (IST)
info: Job completed:
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is a good idea to call that stop() methode, why is it called a Batch Job then ?
The stop() method will terminate the batch and will not execute again at the next scheduled time.
I believe it is made for debugging purposes like stopping the Job when catching an error or something like this.